# Cauchy-Stieltjes transform of a simple function

Tags: complex-analysis

i would like to compute Cauchy transform of function:
$$ f(x) = x e^{-x^2} $$
that is:
$$ g(z) = \int_\mathbf{R} \frac{f(x)dx}{x-z}$$

How can i conduct such a calculation?

Maybe you could also/just give me some readable (i am not a mathematician and i find it difficult to get a good literature on the subject) references on Cauchy/Stieltjes/Hilbert transform since these are interrelated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to calculate in a certain path ?

Comment: yes, along the real axis.

Comment: Simple, ask Mathematica! She tells me $e^{-z^2} z \left(-\pi  \text{erfi}(z)+\log \left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)+\log (z)\right)+\sqrt{\pi }$ where $\Im(z) \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, i would like however to understand the details of the calculation :).

Answer (score 2):

let $z=x+iy $ than $$ g(z) = \int \frac{f(x)dx}{-yi}=\frac{1}{-yi}\int f(x)dx=\frac{1}{-yi}\int e^{-x^2}/2$$
I am not sure about this solution i tried to find $ f(z)$ so that $ Re(f(z))=f(x)$ .

Than by Cauchy  $ g(z) = 2\pi i f(z)$ where z is in the real line.

I hoped that this will help you, even though its probably not the answer you have expected.

Comment: ok, this seems like a start however according to your calculation $g(z=x+iy)=0$ because of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} = 0$. But this solves it only on the imaginary line $z=x+iy$. Thanks for the hint though.